# Loading Bar For Pdf.js

Tags: javascript, pdf, gwt, progress-bar, pdf.js

I want to create a loading bar for pdf.js so the user can monitor how far along pdf.js is with downloading a pdf document to be rendered. My app is run in through gwt, with the pdf.js pdf reader, although I don't think this question has much to do with gwt. In the pdf.js code, there is an bject called progressCallback, which should give me the total amount of data in the pdf to be rendered, and the amount that has been loaded. It's used in methods such as getDocument i.e.

```
PDFJS.getDocument = function getDocument(source,
                                     pdfDataRangeTransport,
                                     passwordCallback,
                                     progressCallback) {
```

here is another method that utilizes it, and shows how it is used

```
messageHandler.on('DocProgress', function transportDocProgress(data) {
    if (this.progressCallback) {
      this.progressCallback({
        loaded: data.loaded,
        total: data.total
      });
```

I was wondering how I would use progressCallback. I can't find a way to access the loaded variable sucesfully. So far, amongst other things, I have tried setting alert windows with the value of progressCallback.loaded and it hasn't worked. Any suggestions for how to make a progressBar using this progressCallback variable? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you opening a remote PDF file, or local?

Comment: Its a remote PDF, stored on a server. It takes about 15 seconds to load, time spent mostly on retrieving the document, which is why a progress bar would help a bit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use it in the following way:

```
var progressCallback = function(progress){
    var percentLoaded = progress.loaded / progress.total;
    console.log(progress); // Progress has loaded and total
};

PDFJS.getDocument = function getDocument(source,
                                     pdfDataRangeTransport,
                                     passwordCallback,
                                     progressCallback) {
// Do something...
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This does not seem to work,  I don't get any progress logged but the PDF still loads?

Comment: I've used it without a problem, could you create a fiddle of your code and paste a link here?

Comment: I think its because I'm waiting a loader for the time it takes to render the PDF, I see it downloading but it takes a long time once the download is finished to render the PDF onto canvas.

Comment: Works but console warning `Deprecated API usage: getDocument is called with pdfDataRangeTransport, passwordCallback or progressCallback argument`. So this is the API 1.0 way. What is the API 2.0 way? Also the callback values appear to **overshoot** to 102% or 113% (loaded ends up bigger than total).

Comment: `console.log("Progress " + Math.round(progress.loaded * 100 / progress.total).toString() + "%");`

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
//load document
var loadingTask = pdf.getDocument(src);

//get progress data
loadingTask.onProgress = function(data){
   console.log( "loaded : " + data.loaded" )
   console.log( "total : " + data.total ")
}

//use document
loadingTask.promise.then( function (pdf){
   //do anything with pdf
}
```

hope it gonna work